# How to complete this bowl picture in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, photo-editing, image-editing, adobe-photoshop-elements

I need to complete the missing part of this picture the right way.

[image]

Comment: What have you tired? Where is it failing?

Answer (score 1):

You need to select a bit of the existing bowl, copy and paste as a new layer, move and rotate to overlay the missing edge, then use a combination of eraser brushing around the edges (with medium brush hardness), some tilting and scaling, maybe add a bit of noise, and you get something like this.

[image]